# Is it possible to write a script that appends a "#" to any line of a file that begins with a capital letter?

Tags: files, scripting, case

In order to make a school project easier, I want to append a delimiter to each line beginning with a capital letter with a bash script. Could anyone help me out? I've tried reading the file line-by-line in tandem with the case command but it doesn't work I don't really understand what I'm doing. This is what i have so far: (I'm new to scripting, don't flame me)

```
#!/bin/bash
input=/home/user/file
while IFS= read -r var
do
        case [A-Z]
                sed 's/^/#/' file
done
```

Comment: It should be faster/better to simply do `sed '/^[A-Z]/s/^/#/' "$input"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You don't use shell loops to process text](/q/169716). Processing text is done by text processing tools which are the ones that process their input one line at a time:

```
#! /bin/sh -
input=/home/user/file
sed 's/^[[:upper:]]/#&/' < "$input"
```

Would insert a `#` before an uppercase letter found at the start (`^`) of each line of `$input`.

Here, uppercase letter is as determined by the locale. It will include the ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ English letters, and possibly things like Á, Ź, or Π if present.

If you wanted to restrict to  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ only, you'd write:

```
sed 's/^[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]/#&/' < "$input"
```

`[A-Z]` itself may match on about anything depending on the locale. You'll find systems where it matches on `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy` (not `z`) as well. On most systems, it would match on Á, but not Ź if present in the locale's charmap. It could even match on sequences of characters (multi-character collating elements like the Hungarian `Ddzs`).

Comment: Why redirect the file `< "$input"` ?

Comment: @Isaac, if you mean as opposed to letting `sed` open the file itself, for a number of reasons. See for instance [Why is \`sort < "$f1" \` preferred over \`sort -- "$f1"\`, and why is this preferred over \`sort "$f1"\`?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/458265)

Comment: But almost the same could be done with `sed "./$input"` and then sed retains the ability to process several files. (If input is not a full path, which in your script it is. That is, it starts with a `/` and so it can not start with a `-`).

Comment: @Isaac, yes if you wanted to process more than one file in one invocation, that's where you couldn't use redirections anymore and have to work around those issues some other way (except with zsh, but that would involve an extra process doing the concatenation behind the scene).